# JavaScript - Find ID that matches data attribute value

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that finds the data attribute of an element that is clicked on in a callback function:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('js-dropdown');

 for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {

   dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", callBack (dropdown[i]));

 }

function callBack (i) {

 return function () {

  var thisDropdown = i.getAttribute('data-dropdown');

  //rest of the code here

  }

}
```

I am basically trying to do this

```
$('#' + thisDropdown ).toggleClass('is-active');
```

**...but in vanilla JS.**

This works fine using jQuery however I would like a vanilla version.

So when a user clicks on an element that activates a drop down, I want it to dynamically find its relevant ID matching value within the document so it can toggle a show/hide class.

I've searched through a lot of SO questions and everyone replies with a jQuery answer which is **not** what I am looking for.

I've been trying to do something along the lines of

```
var idValue = document.getElementById(thisDropdown);
```

Then

```
var findId= idValue + thisDropdown;

findId.toggleClass('is-active');
```

Obviously that does not work the same way the jQuery statement works... any ideas?

Ignore the toggleClass method! Some of you may find this contradictory as I want vanilla JS.

Comment: `$(idValue).toggleClass('is-active')` ?

Comment: @MrGeek He said he doesn't want a jQuery solution.  Vanilla JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace `$('#' + thisDropdown ).toggleClass('is-active');` with plain js, use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Like this:

```
const someElement = document.querySelector('#' + thisDropdown);
someElement.classList.toggle("is-active");
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @kamyl's answer, but you might need backward compatibility.  For that, see if you can find a polyfill.

If you *have* to write it yourself, use `string.split(" ")` to get your list of active attributes and iterate to find if it exists; add if not, remove if so...then `array.join(" ")` and replace the class attribute with it.